# Как сделать ссылки вида /myblogs/?p=53453453453?

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Как можно написать, чтобы ссылки были вида не `/index.php/myblogs/?p=54353`, а `/myblogs/?p=53453453453`?

Comment: Зачем вам .htaccess?

Вроде-как, по дефолту, Apache отсылает запрос к адресу вида "/myblogs/?p=53453453453" на скрипт /myblogs/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В .htaccess пропишите

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^myblogs/([^/\.]+)/?p=$ index.php/myblogs/?p=$1 [L]
```